# Proof for continuous function on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which take on a specific form.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity, analytic-continuation

This is a homework question from Complex Variables by Joseph L. Taylor. The questions reads as follows:

*Prove that if $f$ is a continuous function defined on an open  subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$, then sets of the form {$z\in{U}$:$|f(z)|<r$} and {$z\in{U}$: Re$(f(z))<r$} are open.*

Here is what I have:

Let $f$ be a continuous function and $U$ be an open, non-empty subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $a\in{U}$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that, if $|z-a|<\delta$ then $|f(z)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Let $D$ be a neighborhood around $a$. If $z\in{D_{\delta}(a)}\implies f(z)\in{D_{\epsilon}(f(a))}$. Then $f(D_{\delta}(a))\subseteq D_{\epsilon}(f(a))$. So, $D_{\delta}(a)\subseteq f^{-1}(D_{\epsilon}(f(a)))$.

Here is where I am having a hard time, connecting where I am at to {$z\in{U}$:$|f(z)|<r$} and {$z\in{U}$: Re$(f(z))<r$}. I spoke with my professor and he says that I need to show how $f^{-1}(D_{\epsilon}(f(a)))\subseteq f^{-1}(D_r(0))$, i.e. I have one property left to prove. But I am seriously drawing a blank.

I drew this picture to help me visualize what is happening, but I feel like I am missing pieces in it, or it is not drawn properly. [image]

Any help will be much appreciated. And to be honest, if you feel there are improvements that can be made to how I write proofs I am always open to suggestions for improvement.

Comment: The statement in italics is incomplete.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions $g:x\rightarrow |x|$ and $h:x\rightarrow Re(x)$ are continue, thus $(g\circ f)^{-1}(0,r)$ and $(h\circ f)^{-1}(0,r)$ are open.